# Object disapeared after saving

Tags: objects

I worked on a mesh for hours, then I saved it. Today, I just opened my blend back and it simply disappeared (while everything else is still here). It's not hidden, nor on another layer...
Using Blender 2.79 on Linux Mint 18.2, if that can help.

Comment: did you try File>Recover last session ?

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information. We don't know how you set up your project. Add images that might help us understand your scene. Consider sharing your .blend file so that others can inspect it. You can upload it at http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and then paste the resulting link as part of your question.

Answer (score 2):

This has happened to me before it was to do with the timeline try sliding it back to frame 0 and see if it is there. f you are not animating anything it is advisable to not have the timeline open as it can easily be accidentally clicked

Comment: Just tried this, but it didn't worked...

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the regular recovery options (check File > Recover Auto Save and Recover Last Session), to check if it's truly gone make a new file then try to append the object from your file or one of the auto/recovered saves (File > Append). This lets you browse inside the file and if the object is still there you can try appending it.

Answer (score 0):

If you see it in the outliner then select it, then hit the <kbd>/</kbd> key in the number pad and it should come to view. Sometimes it's just out of clip view.